# @Autowired annotation not able to inject bean in JUnit class

Tags: java, spring, junit

my test class:

```
public class myTest extends TestCase{
@Autowired
BeanClass beanObject
public void beanTest()
{
Classdata data = beanObject.getMethod();
}
}
```

I am getting a null pointer exception at line:

```
Classdata data = beanObject.getMethod();
```

the `beanObject.getMethod();` precisely gives nullpointer exception

How should i make possible the autowiring of the field beanObject in my Junit class so that i can use the methods from the "BeanClass" class?

---

Copied from Comments:

> in plain terms.. beanClass is an
>   interface which has certain methods..
>   i have tagged that beanClass with
>   `@Service("beanObject")`
>   annotation..that banClass is
>   implemented by beanClassImpl class
>   which has the method implementations..
>   i need to use those implementations in
>   my testClass to get the data to be
>   compared.. for that i am doing
>   `@Autowired` beanClass beanObject in
>   my testClass.. m i going terribly
>   wrong somewhere?

Comment: Where is Spring supposed to get the `beanObject` from?  Have you declared it somewhere?

Comment: beanObject already is a beanClass object,where i have declared the beanClass as a @Service("beanObject") annotation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably need to decorate your tests with these annotations:

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {/* your xml locations here */})
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
```

Or, if you use JUnit 3.x, you should extend from `AbstractJUnit38SpringContextTests`

**Reference:** [TestContext support classes](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/testing.html#testcontext-support-classes)

**Update:** The problem seems to be that the context file can't be found (see discussion in comments).

> in plain terms.. beanClass is an
>   interface which has certain methods..
>   i have tagged that beanClass with
>   @Service("beanObject")
>   annotation..that banClass is
>   implemented by beanClassImpl class
>   which has the method implementations..
>   i need to use those implementations in
>   my testClass to get the data to be
>   compared.. for that i am doing
>   @Autowired beanClass beanObject in my
>   testClass.. m i going terribly wrong
>   somewhere?

**More Updates:**

Don't annotate the interface, annotate the implementing class. Annotating the interface with `@Service` has no effect!

Comment: @ContextConfiguration(locations = {spring-servlet.xml}) @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)

Comment: @user582811 OK, then you should edit the question and show the relevant parts of `spring-servlet.xml`

Comment: @user582811 under WEB-INF? And the test finds the context file?

Comment: the test is not able to find the context file

Comment: @user582811: thought so. try this: `locations = "classpath:WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml"`

Comment: since the test was not able to find the context file...i tried putting the spring-servlet.xml directly under root folder that is src.and then the two statements @ContextConfiguration(locations = {"spring-servlet.xml") @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class) ..but in vain\

Comment: but if WEB-INF is inside src/main/webapp that won't help either, then you'll have to use "file:src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml"

Comment: @user582811 use prefixes, either classpath: or file:. Reference: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/resources.html#resources-resourceloader

Comment: i tried this:@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations={"classpath:WEB-INF/liiraWeb-servlet.xml"}) and public class myTest extends TestCase{ @Autowired BeanClass beanObject public void beanTest() { Classdata data = beanObject.getMethod(); } }..... still it gives nullpointer... m sorry m a newbie to springs... but m giving my efforts... and really appreciate ur help in it.. this autowiring thing does not seems to work in a junit class...

Comment: also tried to manually autowire the bean like--->ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring-servlet.xml");
   context.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory().autowireBean(beanObject);.. this attempt too it is not able to find the context file!!

Comment: @user582811 autowiring is not the problem, but spring contexts usually don't reside under WEB-INF, and WEB-INF is usually not on the class path during development

Comment: thats what i did.. i relocated the spring-servlet.xml file under src folder outside of the web-inf folder and then tried autowiring.. still no progress!

Comment: in plain terms.. beanClass is an interface which has certain methods.. i have tagged that beanClass with @Service("beanObject") annotation..that banClass is implemented by beanClassImpl class which has the method implementations.. i need to use those implementations in my testClass to get the data to be compared.. for that i am doing @Autowired beanClass beanObject in my testClass.. m i going terribly wrong somewhere?

Comment: yes i did that.. annotated the implementing class with @Service("beanObject")... and tried using beanClassImpl autowiring... but still the same.. nullpointerexception

Comment: @alpesh003 yes, obviously, if the context file isn't found then the bean isn't wired either. Sorry, I don't mean to be rude, but the info I get from you is too vague and I actually have work to do :-)

Comment: Thanx a lot... actually the run configurations were picking up JUnit 3 and also had to make some connection factory related settings in the spring-servlet.xml file... its solved... thanx for ur help and valuable time! :)

Comment: @SeanPatrickFloyd how to solve this above issue if am not using servlet.xml in my project... Please Help