# @Autowired objects getting null value

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, autowired

Trying to set up a project but fail at Autowiring objects through Spring.

```
package se.hsr.web;

public class TestRunner {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ContactDAO cd = new ContactDAOImpl();
        Contact contact = new Contact();
        contact.setFirstname("Zorro");
        cd.addContact(contact);
    }

}

package se.hsr.web;
```

Running this gives me a NullPointerException when cd.addContact is invoked.
The ContactDaoImpl:

```
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public class ContactDAOImpl implements ContactDAO {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public void addContact(Contact contact) {
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(contact);
    }
```

My servlet file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan
        base-package="se.hsr.web"/>

    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass"
            value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="propertyConfigurer"
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"
        p:location="/WEB-INF/jdbc.properties" />

    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close"
        p:driverClassName="${jdbc.driverClassName}"
        p:url="${jdbc.databaseurl}" p:username="${jdbc.username}"
        p:password="${jdbc.password}" />  

     <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="configLocation">
            <value>classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml</value>
        </property>
        <property name="configurationClass">
            <value>org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration</value>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${jdbc.dialect}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="contactDAOImpl"
        class="se.hsr.web.ContactDAOImpl"/>

    <context:annotation-config/>

</beans>
```

My hibernate.cfg.xml file:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
    "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <mapping class="se.hsr.web.Contact" />
    </session-factory>

</hibernate-configuration>
```

My web.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
    <display-name>HSRMVC</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>HSR</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>HSR</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

I suppose the error is that the SessionFactory isn't getting initialized via @Autowired correctly, but why is that? Could it be a simple directory structure/filepath problem or is it something more complicated?

Thanks in advance.

UPDATE:
ContactDAOImpl class:

```
@Repository
public class ContactDAOImpl extends HibernateDaoSupport implements ContactDAO{

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("sessionFactory")
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public void addContact(Contact contact) {
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(contact);
    }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is my Spring @Autowired field null?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19896870/why-is-my-spring-autowired-field-null)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In order to use Spring features (autowiring, call to post construct methods or aspects) you need to let Spring instanciate the instances instead of using `new`.

For instance:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ApplicationContext context = AnnotationConfigApplicationContext("se.hsr.web")
    ContactDAO cd = (ContactDAO)context.getBean("contactDAOImpl");
    Contact contact = new Contact();
    contact.setFirstname("Zorro");
    cd.addContact(contact);
}
```

`AnnotationConfigApplicationContext` will scan the classes in the classes in the `se.hsr.web` package to for classes with Spring annotations. It requires Spring 3.0 to work. Before that you should add the following line in your `applicationContext.xml` file:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="se.hsr.web" />
```

Comment: Thanks alot, but this isn't making use of the @Autowired annotation is it? Is there another way to make this work using autowiring?

Comment: @Emil - It is using @Autowired. The point is that dependencies are autowired, but that the root object (ContactDao) needs to be spring-managed for this to happen. If you want spring to autowire beans when you explicitly use new, then looking into the @Configurable annotation.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! Now I get a NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [org.hibernate.SessionFactory] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true), @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value=sessionFactory)}.  Now, as you can see in the HSR-servlet.xml, the sessionFactory bean IS declared. Also I updated the original post with my DAOImpl, which looks right to me? What am I missing?

Comment: @Emil you need to write an `applicationContext.xml` to tell spring how to instanciate you SessionFactory. This file will also tell Spring and Hibernate how to make the link between your bean and the `web.xml` file. See [Spring Hibernate Tutorial](http://xlct.it/elZS3m) and [The Spring series, Part 2: When Hibernate meets Spring](http://xlct.it/exjNgK) for more info.

Comment: I thought my HSR-servlet.xml was essentially a applicationContext file. This is the first time I'm making a Spring MVC as opposed to a Wicket application, with those I've always had an applicationContext. I'll try this out. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Did this, and now I the error "org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Hibernate Session bound to thread, and configuration does not allow creation of non-transactional one here"

Comment: Yup Hibernate is complaining that you are not accessing the database in a transactional context. You should add the @Transactional annotation to your `addContact` method.

Answer (score 2):

You need this at the top of your test class:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
// ApplicationContext will be loaded from "/applicationContext.xml" and "/applicationContext-test.xml"
// in the root of the classpath
@ContextConfiguration(locations={"/applicationContext.xml", "/applicationContext-test.xml"})
public class MyTest {
```

I assumed JUnit4; my oversight.

You do need the context configuration tag in an application context somewhere, but I don't see anyplace in your code where you're actually opening an application context file and creating an ApplicationContext.  Usually that's done in a set up method for your test.  You'll have better luck if you actually create an ApplicationContext somewhere.  Try reading the XML from your CLASSPATH in a setup method and see if that helps.

Comment: I'm sorry my class was misleading, it's not really a testclass, just a class named TestRunner that I created in order to try out the functionality. Does the @ContextConfiguration thing apply though?

Comment: No, you need <context:annotation-config> in your context.xml per Michael Borgwart's answer.

Comment: See my original post for an edited spring config file. The problem still persists.

Comment: I think it has to do with this, going to try it out. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4567512/spring-autowired-messagesource-working-in-controller-but-not-in-other-classes

Answer (score 1):

You need this in your Spring configuration for autowiring to work

```
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" 
....
<context:annotation-config/>
```

Comment: I tried editing my spring-configuration, but the problem persists. I've edited my original post with the new config.

Comment: @Emil: well, this is what caused autowiring to fail for me, but I suppose there are other reasons as well.

Answer (score 1):

Add `@Component/@Repository` to the DAO/DAOImpl.

Answer (score 1):

you are creating the POJO outside of the spring context.

if you really want to be able to instanciate "manually", you can fix this, by adding `<context:spring-configured />` to your configuration, and then annotating `ContactDAOImpl` with `@Configurable`

Answer (score 0):

You need to retrieve the ContactDAO instance from Spring context. You are initing yourself with `new` keyword.

See the below link;

[@Autowired annotation not able to inject bean in JUnit class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4746110/autowired-annotation-not-able-to-inject-bean-in-junit-class)

or if not unit test

```
ClassPathResource resource = new ClassPathResource("beans.xml");
BeanFactory factory = new XmlBeanFactory(resource);
beanFactory.getBean("nameOfYourBean");
```

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/reference/beans.html

Comment: Could you elaborate a little on how you mean I should do that? I tried replacing ContactDAO in the testrunner to @Autowired ContactDAO contactDAO; but it gave me a NullPointerException aswell.